# Use the $in Operator with a Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, json, regex, mongodb

I am trying to write $in query with $regex in mongo + java. It is working fine from mongo shell and I am getting the results:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({ "_id" : { "$in" : [ /^1332444344/]}})
```

However, when I try to executed from my java app, I get no results:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
inQuery.put("_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", input));
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);

// This returns no results
// Query: { "_id" : { "$in" : [ { "$regex" : "/^1332444344/"} ] }}
input = Lists.newArrayList(Pattern.compile("/^1332444344/"));

// The following as well returned nothing
// Query: { "_id" : { "$in" : [ "/^1332444344/" ] }}
input = Lists.newArrayList("/^1332444344/"));
```

The Java Code is adding the double quotes around regex and it seems this is causing the issue.

I also tried the following but got a json parse exception:

```
BasicQuery bq = new BasicQuery("{ \"_id\" : { \"$in\" : [ /^1332444344/ ]}}")
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's the `/`s that are really causing the issue. You can't have a `/` before the start of string (`^`). (Java doesn't use `/` to indicate the start and end of regexes).

Comment: "The Java Code is adding the double quotes around the regex": Q: What exactly do you mean????  Q: Are you familiar with the [escape character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)  (`\\`) for string literals?

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndyTurner. You are right. Lists.newArrayList(Pattern.compile("^1332444344")) worked fine!

Comment: @paulsm4 Meant the quotations are causing the problem. Because the following is not returning results from mongo shell: db.getCollection('collection').find({ "_id" : { "$in" : [ "/^1332444344/"]}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the `/`s that are really causing the issue. You can't have a `/` before the start of string (`^`).

Java doesn't use `/` to indicate the start and end of regexes as other languages do. It uses `"` to mark the start and end, since regexes are written like any other string.

Remove the `/`, at least at the start of the regex; you may well want to remove the one at the end as well (depends on what you're actually trying to match).